# IPAddress or CIDR block matching regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to check a string for any IPv4 address or one of following CIDR blocks: /16 or /24.
So, 192.168.0.1 should match. 192.168.0.0/16 should match. 192.168.0.0/17 should NOT match
I'm using following regex:

```
re.compile(r'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/(16|24))?')
```

This matches all IP addresses but also strings like 192.168.0.0/aaaa

Now, if I change the regex (remove ? at end):

```
re.compile(r'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(/(16|24))')
```

It matches CIDR blocks /16 or /24 but not the IP Addresses(eg, 192.168.0.1) anymore.

Isn't '?' supposed to check a group for optional occurrence? What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I know the IP address regex itself is not perfect, but I'm more interested in getting help on the issue described.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}($|/(16|24))$
```

It checks for `$` (*line end*) or `/` and `16` or `24`.

Just like you said `?` marks a group as optional, which means that it will try to include that in the match if possible. But in some cases it cannot like in `192.168.0.0/aaaa`, but because it is optional it will still match the *other* parts.

That is why the above regex is more suited for your needs. This way you will only get a match if it ends either with `/24`, `/16` or *end of line* eg. `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: Above regex works but also matches a string of form '192.168.0.0/16ddddd'. I need the regex for validation purpose so I added $ at the end of optional pattern as well : r'^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}($|/(16|24)$)'.

Comment: I wanted to match any CIDR block 16-32, so I used this:
/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}($|\/([1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-2]))$/

The ^ and $ help to trim anything before or after the string, too. The main difference is the matching of any number between 16 and 32, this part in the third capture group:
[1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-2]

Answer (score 5):

### Accurate Match

Matches `0.0.0.0` through `255.255.255.255`. If CIDR block specified, then matches only if the CIDR is `16` or `24`. **[In action](http://regexr.com?31v22)**:

```sh
^                                                 # Start string
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.               # A in A.B.C.D
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.               # B in A.B.C.D
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)\.               # C in A.B.C.D
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)($|/(16|24))?    # D in A.B.C.D and /16 or /24
$                                                 # End string
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you feel compelled to approach this with a single regex?  Is it really a nail(*)?  Is there some reason why you can't install and use the [Python IPAddr](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/) module and use it to parse and manipulate your IP addresses?  I guess you could then do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ipaddr
...
mynet = ipaddr.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16')
try:
    other = ipaddr.IPv4Network(other_network_string)
    nm = other.netmask
except ipaddr.AddressValueError:
    other = None
    nm = None

...

if nm and nm == mynet.netnmask:
    be_happy()
```

In other words there's a package where someone has done all the heavy lifting of parsing and manipulating IP Address strings.  How much of that do you really want to redo for your code?  How much time do you want to spend testing your new code and finding the same sorts of bugs that the creators of this package have probably found and fixed?

If I sound like I'm hammering on the point a bit ... it's because this approach seems entirely too similar to attempts to parse HTML (or XML) using regexes rather than using existing, tested, robust parsers which have already been written.

- (If the only tool at hand is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail)

Comment: I'm using the regex for form entry validation. Do you think I should use ipaddr even for form validation? I do use ipaddr in another module where incoming request's IP is actually validated against the stored list.

Comment: I would use it rather than trying to write your own parser/validator.  Ideally this will future proof your code to allow it to easily support IPv6 or alternative ways of representing networks if they are ever developed.  As I said, the maintainers of that module have problem encountered and fixed a few corner cases that you're not likely to think of unless you write a formal lexical parser.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of '?' is a bit more complex (just a bit). You can imagine it like a synonym of the adverb "possibly".
It works this way: IF there's a substring matching my pattern THEN go on with the matching process. I "highlighted" IF and THEN because the semantics of the implication says that, in case the premise is not satisfied, the whole sentence is still true.

Therefore, let's now apply this principle to your case. You put a '?' on a suffix. Let's assume that the former part matches and, now, let's deal with the suffix: if there's a suffix that matches your pattern, the whole string will match. If the suffix doesn't match, there's no problem: the block marked with '?' is "optional" (remember the "possibly" semantics or, equivalently, the implication semantics), therefore the string still matches.

Therefore, putting a '?' block in the last part of your pattern is not very useful, because the string will still match, whether or not there's a matching suffix. Optional blocks are useful only in the middle of a string, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how ? works. But, I was also expecting the remedy.