# Select Range of ip's in first column

Tags: regex, bash

I'm fairly new to Bash and I'm running into an issue.
I've got the following output:

```
159.180.30.159 BVI19987
159.180.30.160 BVI19987
159.180.30.161 BVI19987
159.180.30.162 BVI19987
159.180.30.163 BVI19987
159.180.30.164 BVI19987
159.180.30.165 BVI19987
159.180.30.166 BVI19987
159.180.30.167 BVI19987
159.180.30.168 BVI19987
159.180.30.170 BVI19987
159.180.30.171 BVI19987
159.180.30.172 BVI19987
159.180.30.173 BVI19987
159.180.30.174 BVI19987
159.180.30.175 BVI19987
159.180.30.176 BVI19987
159.180.30.177 BVI19987
159.180.30.178 BVI19987
159.180.30.179 BVI19987
159.180.30.180 BVI19987
159.180.30.181 BVI19987
159.180.30.182 BVI19987
159.180.30.183 BVI19987
159.180.30.184 BVI19987
159.180.30.185 BVI19987
159.180.30.186 BVI19987
159.180.30.187 BVI19987
```

What would be the easiest way to only select ip's from 167 to 180 and get this output:

```
159.180.30.167 BVI19987
159.180.30.168 BVI19987
159.180.30.170 BVI19987
159.180.30.171 BVI19987
159.180.30.172 BVI19987
159.180.30.173 BVI19987
159.180.30.174 BVI19987
159.180.30.175 BVI19987
159.180.30.176 BVI19987
159.180.30.177 BVI19987
159.180.30.178 BVI19987
159.180.30.179 BVI19987
159.180.30.180 BVI19987
```

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: do you also want to filter on rows that start with `159.180.30`? or do you want to display all lines regardless of the first 3 tuples (eg, `200.200.200.170` should also show up in the output)?

Comment: all of the sample rows contain `BVI19987` in the 2nd field; could some rows have something other than `BVI19987` in the 2nd field and if so, do we need to additionally filter on the 2nd field or do we ignore whatever's in the 2nd field?

Comment: please update the question to show the code you've tried, along with the (wrong) results generated by your code

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are not very good for ranges. You can hardcode one like

```
grep -E '^159.180.30.1(6[7-9]|7[0-9]|80)' file
```

A better approach in this case is to use Awk with a custom separator.

```
awk -F '.' '($4+0) >= 167 && ($4+0) <= 180' file
```

Adding 0 to the field forces it to be a pure number, to avoid the behavior where Awk applies lexical sort order to strings (where 17 is "bigger than" 167).

You can obviously add more conditions, like

```
awk -F '.' '$1 == 159 && $2 == 180 && $3 == 30 && ($4+0) >= 167 && ($4+0) <= 180' file
```

or add a regex like

```
awk -F '.' '/^159\.180\.30\./ && ($4+0) >= 167 && ($4+0) <= 180' file
```

When you have a more complex range, like for example a /21 which starts in a single-digit network but straddles a boundary to a dal-digit one, you might be better off with a tool which understands the notation. Quick Duck Duck Going finds e.g. [IPAddress or CIDR block matching regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141206/ipaddress-or-cidr-block-matching-regex) with some simple Python scripts.

Comment: Just as below, the `awk` approach is wrong. An `$4` value of `167 BVI19987` will “work” (compare “correctly”) by chance, whereas the `$4` value of `180 BVI19987` will not make it through that comparison.

Comment: although the above works nicely, I've failed to mention that there ar ip's such as 149.143.84.17 & 149.143.84.18 which it then also hits.

Comment: See update now. Generally, try to include a representative data set in your question in the first place to avoid having to move the goalposts after you have received answers.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, the straightforward (and hopefully not awkward) way:

```
 awk -F'[ .]' '167 <= $4 && $4 <= 180' file
```

- `-F[ .]` split columns on the `.` and   (space) character
- `$4` is the 4th field

Comment: Example 4th field contents: `167 BVI19987`. That works by chance for `>= 167` thanks to `awk`’s duck typing, but the other side of the interval won’t be so lucky; this evaluates to `0`: `awk 'BEGIN { print "180 BVI19987" <= 180 }'`.

Comment: Try with new command

Comment: although the above works nicely, I've failed to mention that there ar ip's such as 149.143.84.17 & 149.143.84.18 which it then also hits.

Comment: Which `awk` & platform are you running ???

Comment: @Thijs if the example in your question doesn't adequately represent your real data, don't just mention that in a comment - edit your question to fix your example.

Comment: @Thijs: not with the new code

Answer (score 1):

In pure Bash:

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  IFS=$'. \t\n' read -ra fields <<< "$line"
  ((fields[3] >= 167 && fields[3] <= 180)) && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < input_file
```

In `awk` (shorter and with “more universal” whitespace matching):

```bash
awk -F'[[:space:].]' '$4 >= 167 && $4 <= 180' < /tmp/input
```

(Side note: This approach [hurts the internet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YgiM5K16mlRWwqf6DNKU3--IkmtEViyN72MADgTPcZs/preview) and should be avoided; if IPv4 cannot be avoided, consider IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses in their hexadecimal-only form, for broader compatibility.)

Answer (score 1):

To properly parse IPv4, better use a proper parser, here in `Perl`:

```
perl -F'\s|\.' -MRegexp::Common -lane '
    print if /^$RE{net}{IPv4}/ && $F[3] >= 157 && $F[3] <= 180
' file
```

Check [perldoc Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `sed` program can do it:

```bash
sed -n -E '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}167 /,/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}180 /p'
```

It prints (`p`) each line starting with the one that matches the first regex (`([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}167`) until and including the one that matches the second regex.

The regular expressions match three groups (`{3}`) of 1 to 3 digits (`[0-9]{1,3}`) each of them followed by a dot (`\.`), followed by `167` (or `180`) followed by a space. Use `\t` instead of space ( ) if your input uses tabs to separate the columns. Or drop it altogether.

The `-n` option tells `sed` to not print each input line (as it does by default). The `p` command is the one that prints the lines that match.

The `-E` option tells `sed` to use modern regular expressions. By default `sed` uses basic regular expressions; the program can be expressed using them too but it would be more verbose because the basic regular expressions are more simple and do not support some new additions to the regular expressions syntax (well, they were "new" 30 years ago but `sed` is 20 years older than that.)

If the input contains IP addresses from multiple ranges and you want only those starting with `159.180.30.` then replace `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}` with a more specific expression:

```bash
sed -n -E '/^159\.180\.30\.167 /,/^159\.180\.30\.180 /p'
```

#### Remark

The code above does not care if the groups of digits and dots represent valid addresses or anything else. It relies on the fact that the lines to be output are consecutive. It does not do any numeric comparison and it does not understand that `170` is between `167` and `180`. All it cares about are the start line and the end line.

It might not produce the expected outcome if the rows are shuffled!

Comment: This assumes the input is sorted.

Comment: @tripleee That's what it says. Check the paragraph that starts with _"The code above..."_. :-)